# When using rhandsontable how do I stop hot_to_r adding a column on download

Tags: r, shiny, rhandsontable

I'm trying to write a simple shiny app to upload a .csv file, edit it then download it.  I'm almost there only the downloaded file has an extra column of row numbers.  Any suggestions on how I suppress this?

Here's my code:

```
library(rhandsontable)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Upload, edit and save a csv file"),
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        fileInput('file1', 'Choose CSV File',
                  accept=c('text/csv', 
                           'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', 
                           '.csv')),
         downloadButton('downloadData', 'Download')
      ),
      mainPanel(
        rHandsontableOutput("hot")
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

    getData <- reactive({
      req(input$file1) # Don't run any more code until the user has selected this
      inFile <- input$file1
      read.csv(inFile$datapath, header=T)
    })

    output$hot = renderRHandsontable({
       req(input$file1) # Don't run any more code until the user has selected this
       if (!is.null(input$hot)) {
          rhandsontable(hot_to_r(input$hot))
        } else {
          rhandsontable(getData())
        }
    })
 
    output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
       filename = function() { 
         paste("data-", Sys.Date(), ".csv", sep="")
       },
       content = function(file) {
         write.csv(hot_to_r(input$hot), file)
       }
    )
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `readr::write_csv()` to avoid the extra column or `write.csv(hot_to_r(input$hot), file, row.names = FALSE)` with row.names argument set to FALSE.

```
output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() { 
        paste("data-", Sys.Date(), ".csv", sep="")
    },
    content = function(file) {
        readr::write_csv(hot_to_r(input$hot), file)
    }
)
```